# iptables block fragmented flow that contain specific string

Tags: bash, security, iptables

I want to block traffic that contain specific string `"anypattern"`.

I know that the right iptables rule for that is:

```
iptables -m string --algo bm --string "anypattern" -j DROP
```

The problem that the data could be split to many TCP sequences. And there is a risk that the string `"anypattern"` could be split in 2 packets. For example the packet 1 will contains `"anyp"` and the second packet will contains `"attern"`

How I can make iptables detect TCP fragmentation and make the check on the final tcp payload?
Or are there a solution for such issue?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to span multiple packets with any iptables rule, they apply on a per packet basis. Reassembling multiple packets into an overall payload happens at higher level, after iptables handles the packets.

Comment: could be done by DPI modules or by IDS but unfortunally not with iptables